# Does the speed of programming language depend on compiler?

Tags: performance, compiler-construction, compilation, programming-languages

I am trying to learn how computer programs work and have this question. I often read articles like "C/C++ are faster than java" or "Java and C#: speed comparison". In all cases programs written in any language is translated to assembly language. So, what is the reason of speed differences in those languages. Does that mean, the compiler of one language generates better and faster assembly code ?

Comment: Writing a comment when down-voting is kind of good thing. Down-voting loses the point if you don't know why somebody did that

Comment: "In all cases programs written in any language is translated to assembly language." This is *not* true, and is probably one of the biggest factors in performance differences between the languages you've mentioned.

Comment: @twalberg Then how computer understands the code. Maybe it directly does not translate to assembly but in any ways it ends up as assembly, am I right?

Comment: Well, for one, Java code "runs" in a "Java Virtual Machine (JVM)" after being compiled to "bytecode" - i.e. it's interpreted or emulated, not converted to machine code and run directly. C or C++ on the other hand, are compiled to machine code and run directly on the hardware. Ultimately what runs on the CPU is machine code, yes, but in some cases what is running is not the code you wrote, but something that interprets a representation of the code you wrote...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort of.

There are several reasons why speeds will differ between compilers/interpreters/programming languages, some of it having to do with the compiler, and some of it having to do with the language itself.

#### Some programming languages require more overhead.

If your language is very high level, it'll have more overhead compared to C, which is very low level. (garbage collection is a good example of this). It becomes a tradeoff. Do I want blazing fast binaries, or do I want to be able to write programs easily?

#### Languages are designed to do different things.

For example, PHP is designed to be used on web servers, and nobody in their right mind would try and use it to create a top-tier fps game. Different languages are better suited for different tasks, and will be faster in some areas then in others.

#### Not all languages compile to assembly.

While C/C++ may compile to assembly, languages like Java instead compile to bytecode and is run against the java virtual machine, for interoperability reasons. Once again, this is a tradeoff -- you gain portability at the expense of overhead.

Furthermore, C/C++ doesn't even *have* to compile to assembly. For example, enscriptem ultimately will compile C/C++ to Javascript so it can run on web browsers.

#### Compilers are not magic.

They're programs, and like all programs, have bugs and will improve (or degrade) over time. I could try writing a C compiler over the weekend, and I'd bet a million dollars that it would perform several orders of magnitude worse then a compiler/interpreter for the slowest language you can think of.

#### Compiler/interpreter optimization is an ongoing field of research and study.

Every year, researchers are writing and publishing papers on a new way to compile and make programs run faster. If a language is newer, it may not yet have had the time to fully apply every optimization available. (see above). Some optimizations may apply to only one kind of compiler/interpreter.

---

So, to summarize, the speed of a language is a mixture of the intrinsic features of the language itself, along with the maturity of the compiler/interpreter/platform used.

Compilers and interpreters are not some monolithic magical process that's constant between all programming languages -- they're all different, have different benefits and disadvantages, and are constantly in a state of flux.

Comment: Bet me to it. :) Maybe giving examples as to how compilers optimize code in the most crude sense can help the OP better understand. Like  inline fixing of small methods, or rearranging code to increase throughput if they can be interchanged without loss of program logic, etc.